Pyspark sentiment analysis invalid output
I am trying to perform sentiment analysis for a use case. Most of the time, it is giving correct results, but in some cases, even positive comments are being marked as negative. How can I fix my code to achieve better accuracy?
My code
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from transformers import pipeline
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

# Define the filter_stopwords function
def filter_stopwords(sentence):
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(sentence)
    filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words]
    return " ".join(filtered_sentence)

# Initialize the sentiment analysis pipeline with a different model
sentiment_pipeline = pipeline("sentiment-analysis", model="distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english")

# Define a function to get sentiment using the pipeline
def get_sentiment(text):
    filtered_text = filter_stopwords(text)
    result = sentiment_pipeline(filtered_text)[0]
    return result['label'].lower()  # returns 'positive', 'negative', etc.

# Register the function as a UDF
sentiment_udf = udf(get_sentiment, StringType())

# df = df.withColumn("sentiment", sentiment_udf(col("text_column")))

Input data

Didn't get it right the first 2 times but when it was fixed it was fixed well.

The Response time was grate -- Note Looks like spelling mistake but his review is positive

The initial agent contact could not resolve my issue but escalated it quickly to someone who could.


for this inputs i am expecting all should be positive instead i am getting negative

could the issue come from the model ?

Your code is perfectly fine, but the issue lies with how the model interprets your inputs, not with the implementation itself.
I ran your inputs directly on the Hugging Face model page for distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english.
The first example ("Didn't get it right the first 2 times but when it was fixed it was fixed well") returns positive as expected.
The other two examples, however, return negative, confirming that the issue isn’t your code but how the model processes those inputs.
These models are trained on general datasets and are likely to misinterpret domain-specific or nuanced inputs, especially ones with mixed sentiment signals or spelling mistakes like "grate" in your example. Phrases like "could not resolve my issue" in your third input might outweigh the positive sentiment in "escalated it quickly to someone who could."
I suggest you explore the following:

Test your outlier examples on different sentiment analysis models directly on HhuggingFace. You might find models that are more aligned with the nature of your data.
Preprocess your data to fix spelling mistakes and/or rephrase ambiguous or mixed sentiment phrases.
At last, if still not satisfied with the results and can't tolerate the marginal error, you should then annotate your data and use it to fine-tune a sentiment analysis model.


Your current implementation faces two key issues:

Loss of Context: Removing stopwords can inadvertently remove critical words (e.g., "not", "but") that are essential for determining sentiment.

Model Suitability: The distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english model might not be optimal for conversational or review-style texts like your examples.


Here’s an optimized version of your code that addresses these issues:
# Sample DataFrame
data = [
    ("Didn't get it right the first 2 times but when it was fixed it was fixed well.",),
    ("The Response time was grate",),  # Typo: "grate" should be "great"
    ("The initial agent contact could not resolve my issue but escalated it quickly to someone who could.",),
]
columns = ["text_column"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

# Load the sentiment analysis pipeline
sentiment_pipeline = pipeline("sentiment-analysis", model="cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-sentiment")

# Extract id2label mapping from the model
id2label = sentiment_pipeline.model.config.id2label

# Define a function to perform sentiment analysis
def get_sentiment_with_label(text):
    try:
        # Correct spelling with TextBlob
        corrected_text = str(TextBlob(text).correct())
        
        # Perform sentiment analysis
        result = sentiment_pipeline(corrected_text)
        
        # Extract label and score
        label_id = result[0]['label']  # e.g., 'LABEL_1'
        score = result[0]['score']
        
        # Map the label to human-readable text
        human_readable_label = id2label[int(label_id.split('_')[1])]
        
        # Return the result as a formatted string
        return f"{human_readable_label} (score: {round(score, 4)})"
    except Exception as e:
        return "error"  # Handle errors gracefully

# Register the function as a UDF
sentiment_with_label_udf = udf(get_sentiment_with_label, StringType())

# Apply UDF to the DataFrame
df = df.withColumn("sentiment_analysis", sentiment_with_label_udf(col("text_column")))

# Show the results
df.show(truncate=False)

Output
For your input data, this code produces the following output:
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|text_column                                                                                        |sentiment_analysis          |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|Didn't get it right the first 2 times but when it was fixed it was fixed well.                     |positive (score: 0.4776)     |
|The Response time was grate                                                                        |positive (score: 0.6408)     |
|The initial agent contact could not resolve my issue but escalated it quickly to someone who could.|positive (score: 0.5880)     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+

